# Add RandomForestClassifier Predict_Proba Results to Original Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random-forest

I'm a newbie working on my first 'real' ML algorithm. Apologies if this is duplicated but I can't find the answer on SO.

I've got the following dataframe (`df`):

```
index    Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  Target
001       01         01        03        0
002       03         03        01        1
003       03         02        02        1
```

My code looks something like this:

```
data = df[['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3']]
labels = df['Target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.8)

clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)

prediction_of_probability = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

What I'm struggling with is how can I get the `'prediction_of_probability'` back into the dataframe `df`?

I understand the predictions would not be for all items in the original dataframe.

Thank you in advance for helping a newbie like me!

Comment: Do you want to replace `y_test` or want entirely new column?

Comment: Also, what does the data frame `prediction_of_probability` look like? Can you share a few rows of its output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to keep the indices of the train and test and then put it all together this way:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = df[['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3']]
labels = df['Target']
indices = df.index.values 

# use the indices instead the labels to save the order of the split.

X_train, X_test,indices_train,indices_test = train_test_split(data,indices, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

y_train, y_test = labels[indices_train],  labels[indices_test]


clf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)

prediction_of_probability = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Then you can put the probabilities in the new `df_new`:

```
>>> df_new = df.copy()
>>> df_new.loc[indices_test,'pred_test'] = prediction_of_probability # clf.predict_proba(X_test)
>>> print(df_new)

   Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  Target  pred_test
1         3         3         1       1        NaN
2         3         2         2       1        NaN
0         1         1         3       0        1.0
```

And even the predictions for the train:

```
>>> df_new.loc[indices_train,'pred_train'] = clf.predict_proba(X_train)
>>> print(df_new)

   Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  Target  pred_test  pred_train
1         3         3         1       1        NaN         1.0
2         3         2         2       1        NaN         1.0
0         1         1         3       0        1.0         NaN
```

Or if you want to mix the probabilities of train and test, just use the same column name (i.e. `pred`).

Answer (score 7):

What you did is training the model. It means that with the features and the label you have, you train the model for future data. 
To test the quality of the model(selection of features for example), the model is tested on the X_test and y_test.
In this case, you dont have future data, so you are not applying your model, you are just training it. You can see the quality of your model with AUC or ROC curves.

Anyway you can append the results to the dataframe in this way:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
df_test['Target'] = y_test
df_test['prob_0'] = prediction_of_probability[:,0] 
df_test['prob_1'] = prediction_of_probability[:,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
# Create new dataframe to store test data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
df1['Target'] = y_test
df1['prob'] = prediction_of_probability[:,0]  

# Create another dataframe to store train data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
df2['Target'] = y_train

# Append both dataframes
df = df1.append(df2).sort_index()
```